# Flutter While function not doing what it's ask to

Tags: flutter, dart, while-loop

```
class Player {
final String playerName;
final int playerValue;

Player({this.playerName, this.playerValue});

static List<Player> pairPlayers() {
final List<Player> playersList = [
  Player(playerName: 'Cristiano', playerValue: 20),
  Player(playerName: 'Messi', playerValue: 20),
  Player(playerName: 'Cristiano', playerValue: 30),
  Player(playerName: 'Cristiano', playerValue: 50),
  Player(playerName: 'Messi', playerValue: 20),
];

playersList.shuffle();
var player1 = playersList.first;
var player2 = player1;
while (player1.playerValue == player2.playerValue) {
  playersList.shuffle();
   player2 = playersList.first;
 }

return [player1, player2];

}

@override
String toString() {
  return playerName;
 }
}
```

So I'm using this class to provide me with two players. The problem is that it's still giving me players with the same value. Could anyone please help? 
Here's the stateful widget I'm using it in:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './playerClass.dart';

 class ComparisonInterface extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _ComparisonInterfaceState createState() => _ComparisonInterfaceState();
}

class _ComparisonInterfaceState extends State<ComparisonInterface> {
Player player1 = Player.pairPlayers().elementAt(0);
Player player2 = Player.pairPlayers().elementAt(1);
 _ComparisonInterfaceState();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   void initState() {
    Player.pairPlayers();

    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      player1.playerName +
          'is valued at ' +
          player1.playerValue.toString() +
          '\$, ' +
          player2.playerName +
          "'s value is " +
          player2.playerValue.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text(
                'Higher',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 60),
              )),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text(
                'Lower',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 60),
              )),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

}
If you know how to fix it please provide me with some details to understand what's happening to use this way of thinking for future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this :

```
Player player1 = Player.pairPlayers().elementAt(0); 
Player player2 = Player.pairPlayers().elementAt(1);
```

You call pairPlayers() twice, and because of shuffle you get 2 random players.
If you want a pair of player with different values (which your pairPlayers correctly provides) you should call it only once, like this :

```
 List<Player> pair = Player.pairPlayers();
 Player player1 = pair[0];
 Player player2 = pair[1];
```